# Green insects on gooseberry plants

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

I have green insects that eat the leaves of my gooseberry plants:

[image]

1. Location: Toronto, Ontario.
2. The insects seem to only eat the leaves of the plants (not the fruit).
3. They have been present since mid-May, and I expect that they'll be present until mid-June, based on past experience.
4. They do not have spots.

**What is the name of this insect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The species name of this insect is the [gooseberry saw fly](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=517). There are three related species, I think this is the **pale spotted gooseberry sawfly** because it has a pale green head. They usually have black dots as well, but this might develop when the larvae grow. At least, this is what I observed once in my garden.